# Formal Methods : How to install CZT plugin on Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ide, ubuntu-16.04, formal-methods

I've read [this](http://czt.sourceforge.net/eclipse/download.html) and [this](http://czt.sourceforge.net/dev/eclipse/). They both couldn't help me with this issue. In [this](http://czt.sourceforge.net/eclipse/updates/nightly/) link, there seems to be nothing in the repository and in [this](http://czt.sourceforge.net/dev/eclipse/) link, I followed every single step it says, but still couldn't get [CZT](http://czt.sourceforge.net/) plugin for my Eclipse IDE.

How can I install [CZT](http://czt.sourceforge.net/) plugin for Eclipse IDE?

**Note**: My operating system is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It seems that there is a version of Eclipse IDE existed in .exe format with CZT plugin already enabled on it. But since my operating system does not support .exe files, I can not fix this problem this way.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- Download [this .jar file](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~marku/czt/net.sourceforge.czt.eclipse_1.0.2.jarhttp://) and [this .jar file](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~marku/czt/net.sourceforge.czt.eclipse.help_1.0.2.jar) both.
>
> 2- Put this two .jar files into your **plugins** folder of Eclipse.
>
> 3- Restart your Eclipse IDE.

Now you have **CZT** plugin installed on your Eclipse IDE.

But for creating a new CZT project do the following steps:

> 1- Go to **File - > New - > Project - > CZT - > CZT project**
>
> 2- Specify the name of your project then click finish.
>
> 3- Right click on your project and go to **New - > Z Specification**
>
> 4- Specify the name of file and the directory of it and then Click
>   finish.

Now you can write your **Z Specification** in this new file.

[Here](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~marku/czt/eclipsereference.pdf) is a PDF file that clearly describes what to do.